# Can I use array.join to take all the integers in my array and combine them into one int?

Tags: c#, arrays, search, join

I have an array with five random numbers that represent lottery balls. Lets say the numbers are [8, 4, 2, 0, 3]. Can I use the array.join method to take all of these numbers from my array and put them into int winningNumber so the winning number is 84,203. I am trying to do this so it is easier to test the winning number when everyone gets random lottery numbers. Edit: Thanks for the comment: Any number cannot reach higher than 9 or below 0 and the first number has to at least be 1

Comment: What if one number has two digits?

Comment: There is no `Array.Join` in C#.

Comment: Sorry the max number in any element is 9 and it can't go below 0 is

Comment: `int.Parse(String.Concat(arr))`

Comment: @L.B He appears to want an `int` variable.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) like:

```
int[] array = new int[] { 8, 4, 2, 0, 3 };
string str = string.Join("", array);
```

If you need a number than use `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` like:

```
int number = int.Parse(str);
```

You can also use [`String.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts `IEnumerable<T>` as parameter.

```
string str = string.Concat(array);
```

Both `String.Join` and [`String.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991828(v=vs.110).aspx) works because:

> The string representation of each object in the `IEnumerable<T>`
>   collection is derived by calling that object's ToString method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare your winning sequence to a number of other drawings, you could be using IEnumerable.SequenceEquals instead of this.

In any case, you're already making the problem more complicated than it needs to be, and might try making the algorithm by hand, working with the regular arrays. Reinventing the wheel isn't something you should do too often, but it can be educational sometimes.